# Mercurial Error - Can't Find File

Tags: file, mercurial

I'm just getting started with Mercurial, downloaded and installed hg command-line for Windows, cloned a new BitBucket repository, added a file, but when I commit I get this error:

```
>hg commit -m 'first commit'
abort: commit': The system cannot find the file specified
```

The added file is definitely in the repository folder. When I run hg status I get:

```
A Ant.java
```

And adding --traceback to the commit message gets me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 87, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 684, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 466, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 738, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 692, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyc", line 681, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyc", line 458, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyc", line 1194, in commit
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyc", line 1223, in commit
  File "mercurial\commands.pyc", line 1189, in commitfunc
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyc", line 1036, in commit
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyc", line 1295, in status
  File "mercurial\dirstate.pyc", line 685, in status
  File "mercurial\dirstate.pyc", line 594, in walk
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyc", line 1016, in fail
Abort: commit': The system cannot find the file specified
abort: commit': The system cannot find the file specified
```

In googling the question, lots of references to TortoiseHG appeared. I did used to have that installed, but got rid of it and restarted, there doesn't seem to be anything left on the system. Any ideas as to what I could try, or any mistakes I might have made?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use double quotes: `hg commit -m "first commit"`

Comment: Good catch! We're trying to write our examples in, say, at the bottom of [`hg help revsets`](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) with double quotes since single quotes don't work on Windows.

Comment: Saved me beating someone/something to a pulp :) Atlassian documentation has single quotes and is indeed the issue. Wouldnt be the first time they were wrong :P

Answer (score 1):

Just to note you can get this error due to unwittingly having a space between the dash and the m i.e.
`- m` as opposed to `-m`.